# Search XML Variable in an Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to identify a "node" in an XML string. I do not have any experience with Oracle XML Functions. The XML String is generated in a Stroed Procedure using XMLElement and XMLAgg Functions. How can I identify the value of the node RESULT.NAME?

I have declared a variable in teh Stored Procedure and have tried the following but the Stored Procedure does not compile. It gives me an error saying "Statement ignored"
    vRepResults :=     XMLResults.EXTRACT('ZAVACOR_RESULTS/ORDERS/SAMPLE/TEST/RESULT/REPORTED_RESULT/text()').getstringval();

This string is stored in a variable, not in a Table and hence I am not sure if I can use the XQuery functions. I have pasted the sample XML Below:

```
<ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
    <ORDERS>
        <X_EXTERNAL_ID>508106</X_EXTERNAL_ID>
        <X_ZAV_PROTOCOL></X_ZAV_PROTOCOL>
        <SAMPLE>
            <LABEL_ID>352453611</LABEL_ID>
            <STATUS>I</STATUS>
            <TEST>
                <ANALYSIS>_GLUCOSE_SO1_ENZ_001</ANALYSIS>
                <STATUS>I</STATUS>
                <RESULT>
                    <NAME>GLUCOSE</NAME>
                    <REPORTED_RESULT>
                        <REPORTED_VALUE>3</REPORTED_VALUE>
                    </REPORTED_RESULT>
                </RESULT> 
            </TEST>
        </SAMPLE>
        </ORDERS>
</ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below extracts the value inside  tag. I'm not sure what is the problem with your code, could you provide more of it? Declaration of `vRepResults` and `XMLResults` variables, if you would, and the way `XMLResults` is created.

```
DECLARE
  v_name VARCHAR2(200);
  v_xml_str VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  v_xml_str := 
  '<ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
    <ORDERS>
        <X_EXTERNAL_ID>508106</X_EXTERNAL_ID>
        <X_ZAV_PROTOCOL></X_ZAV_PROTOCOL>
        <SAMPLE>
            <LABEL_ID>352453611</LABEL_ID>
            <STATUS>I</STATUS>
            <TEST>
                <ANALYSIS>_GLUCOSE_SO1_ENZ_001</ANALYSIS>
                <STATUS>I</STATUS>
                <RESULT>
                    <NAME>GLUCOSE</NAME>
                    <REPORTED_RESULT>
                        <REPORTED_VALUE>3</REPORTED_VALUE>
                    </REPORTED_RESULT>
                </RESULT> 
            </TEST>
        </SAMPLE>
    </ORDERS>
  </ZAVACOR_RESULTS>';

  v_name := xmltype(v_xml_str).extract('/ZAVACOR_RESULTS/ORDERS/SAMPLE/TEST/RESULT/NAME/text()').getStringVal();

  dbms_output.put_line(v_name);
END;
```

Output:

```
GLUCOSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Converting the v_xml_str back to xmltype worked.